# PHPList keeps trying to send to a failed address

Tags: email, phplist

I have PHPList (3.2.4) installed on a dedicated server. I did not set particular configuration or limits at the moment. I'm using a local postfix as SMTP.

I sent a campaign and 1 email address gets the following error (in maillog):

```
Recipient address rejected: Domain not found
```

The problem is that phplist keeps trying to send the message to that address, and it doesn't stop the campaing. This is not a bounce, but a failed email, so the campaign never closes, and in the admin interface I keep getting a message:

```
You have 1 message(s) waiting to be sent
```

so that I have to stop the campaign manually.

I'd like to know if I can:

1. set a timeout between retries
2. mark this address as invalid after N retries

I read the documentation, but didn't find what I'm looking for. How can I achieve this result and avoid phplist to retry indefinitely to send to failed addresses?

Could this depend from my Postfix configuration? (e.g. reject instead of bounce)?